# How to close OpenCV window (Python 3) in macOS?

Tags: python-3.x, macos, opencv

I am first time using macOS High Sierra and Spider IDE for Python Programming.

The window does not close when I press **q** key on the keyboard. The output window freezes with the last frame and control returns to the Python prompt.

Any solution or workaround will be much appreciated. I would also love to know the reason.

Following are the details of versions of Python and OpenCV.

Python 3.9.7
OpenCV 4.5.3
Spyder 5import cv2

```
The code is as follows,

import cv2
frameWidth = 640
frameHeight = 480
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(3, frameWidth)
cap.set(4, frameHeight)
cap.set(10,150)
window_name = "Result"
cv2.namedWindow(window_name)

while cap.isOpened():
    success, img = cap.read()
    if success:
        cv2.imshow(window_name, img)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyWindow(window_name)
```

Comment: that's because you are stuck in the loop... because you failed to break the loop when the video ends. -- `isOpened` will remain true forever. it only tells you that the file could be opened and read, NOT that the video has ended. you must check `isOpened` only ONCE after creating the VideoCapture instance. and you MUST check AND BREAK: `if not success: break`. everyone does this wrong because everyone seems to follow badly written "tutorials" or even "video tutorials". having to repeat this all the time is exhausting.

Comment: I replaced it with true, it still does not work peoperly.

Comment: yeah because that's not all I said. I said you have to break out of the loop as well. please don't just ignore everything but the first point.

Answer (score 1):

notice: success variable - is a boolean flag that tells you if the next frame is available to read.

if success is false, you probably reached the end of the video. Then, your program will be stuck in infinite loop because you never meet the conditions of `if success: ...` so you cant reach the command `if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'): break`.

so first thing, you have to change the conditions in your while loop.

change

```
while cap.isOpened():
    success, img = cap.read()
    if success:
        cv2.imshow(window_name, img)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
```

to

```
while cap.isOpened():
        success, img = cap.read()
        if not success:
            break   
        cv2.imshow(window_name, img)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
```

If you still have the same problem, as I had with my Jupyter Notebook, try to add `cv2.waitKey(1)` after destroying the window.

```
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cv2.waitKey(1)
cap.release()
```